# Using ArcGIS server, bing maps no longer free, how and where do i put our bing map license?

Tags: bing-maps, arcgis, arcgis-server

as of january 1st, 2014 the bing maps layer for arcgis is no longer free. esri put out a desktop patch that allows you to input a bing maps key. however, i cannot find anything related to arcgis server. layers are not showing up in our web application all of a sudden so i know the bing maps key needs to be entered or replaced. problem is i inherited this and have a sysadmin background, not GIS background so no idea how to fix this.

anyone bail me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on where to set your Bing Maps key in ArcGIS Server here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//00930000008m000000

If you do not have a Bing Maps key you can find documentation on how to create an account and key here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg650598.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx

You will likely also need a license for Bing Maps as well. You can contact Bing Maps here to verify: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/contact-us.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your web application.  It is something that would be specified in your web application, not your ArcGIS Server.

It is mentioned briefly in the Bing FAQ (http://downloads2.esri.com/ArcGISOnline/docs/bing_faq1.pdf):

> Q: How do I input a new Bing Maps key in my web applications?
>
> A: In your code, you need to search for the Bing Maps key you are
>   currently using. You will need to replace this key with the one you
>   obtain from Microsoft.

So depending on if you are using a FlexViewer application, or a JavaScript/Flex/Silverlight app the exact answer would be slightly different.

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/12/19/final-reminder-bing-maps-use-in-arcgis-has-changed/